# Using React with Nashorn throws "ReferenceError: "console" is not defined"

Tags: java, javascript, reactjs, nashorn

Im using `"react": "~0.12.2"`

And the following code:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
private String home() throws ScriptException, IOException {
    loadReact();
    InputStream jsStream = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:public/js/server.js").getInputStream();
    engine.eval(new InputStreamReader(jsStream));
    return engine.eval("renderServerside()").toString();
}

private void loadReact() throws ScriptException, IOException {
    InputStream jsStream = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:public/lib/react/react.js").getInputStream();

    // React expects 'window' or 'global' to be set
    engine.eval("var global = this");
    engine.eval(new InputStreamReader(jsStream));
}
```

My server.js looks like this:

```
function renderServerside() {
    var MyComponent = React.createClass({
        render: function () {
            return React.DOM.h1(null, 'Hi, ' + this.props.msg)
        }
    });

    return React.renderComponentToString(MyComponent({msg: 'World!'}));
}
```

And getting this exception:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "console" is not defined in <eval> at line number 18108] with root cause

jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAException: ReferenceError: "console" is not defined
```

**So how can nashorn not provide a console?**

I tired to implement the basic example from this page: [React with Nashorn](http://augustl.com/blog/2014/jdk8_react_rendering_on_server/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rhino before it didn't provide one either. You can implement your own console with something like

```
console = { 
    log: print,
    warn: print,
    error: print
};
```

For full blown console support you might need to add more functions. See: [Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/console)

Comment: With a little modification it worked. I will edit the answer.